# comparing current date in firebase database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to save total feedback sent from an app (i am working on) for the current day. If there is no feedback sent i want to put 0 for current date. If there is any i want to increment it. I will be using this data later to populate graphs.

The problem I am facing is it always saves "0" which means the query is not working or maybe I am doing this the wrong way. can you be of any help?

```
   final DatabaseReference TodayLearningReports = 

   firebaseDatabase.getReference("xyz/TotalLearningBehaviourReports");
            Query findtotal=TodayLearningReports.orderByChild(nowDate)
   .equalTo(nowDate);
            findtotal.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot 
      dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists())

   totalLearningFeedbackToday=dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError 
   databaseError) {

                }
            });
            if (totalLearningFeedbackToday.isEmpty())
            {
                TodayLearningReports.child(nowDate).setValue("0");
            }
            else
            {

                int newTotal=Integer.parseInt(totalLearningFeedbackToday);
                TodayLearningReports.child(nowDate).setValue(++newTotal);}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write a new value to a node based on its existing value, use a [Firebase Database transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions). In your case that'd look something like this:

```
TodayLearningReports.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
    @Override
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
        Long value = mutableData.getValue(Long.class);
        if (value == null) {
            mutableData.setValue(1);
        }
        else {
            mutableData.setValue(value + 1);
        }
        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                           DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Transaction completed
        Log.d(TAG, "runTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
    }
});
```

Comment: it is not saving any data to the database

Comment: I missed that you have a query. A transaction can only be run on a `DatabaseReference`, so you'll need to run a query to find the correct node to run the transaction on, but still run a transaction on that node afterwards, to prevent users overwriting changes from other users.